# Database of Ingress portals

Tags: data-request, geospatial, games

Ingress is a game where users contribute "portals".

Each portal has:

- Coordinates
- Name, for instance "Eiffel Tower"
- Picture

Is there a database of all portals, or an API to find portals at least in a given area?
What I mostly need is coordinates, but name+picture would be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The Ingress Terms of Service disallows "extracting, scraping, or indexing" game data. It's possible to get banned if you use this data.

I had the same question and found an answer. A helpful person called Lanced has done the hard work of extracting portal data from the game and provides a public API, available at https://lanched.ru/PortalGet/ However, the author warns not to download the whole database.

There are essentially three ways to use this API:

1. The most basic API takes minimum and maximum bounds in lat/lon coordinates as input and provides GUID, coordinates and title for 1000 portals at a time. You can make several requests (using the `offset=` parameter) to retrieve all portals in a larger area.
2. A more detailed request (using `telegram=true`), which also returns portal image URL and street address, but is limited to 50 portals per request.
3. With the search API you can search for portal names and addresses. This one also returns images and addresses.

### Examples

**Example 1:**
https://lanched.ru/PortalGet/getPortals.php?swlat=59.47106&swlng=24.8862&nelat=59.4719&nelng=24.88749&offset=0

```
{
  "nextOffset": -1,
  "portalData": [
    {
      "guid": "4c95b3ae447d4605a8421e21ace654c4.16",
      "lat": 59.47143,
      "lng": 24.887374,
      "name": "Tallinna Teletorn"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

**Example 2:** https://lanched.ru/PortalGet/getPortals.php?swlat=59.47106&swlng=24.8862&nelat=59.4719&nelng=24.88749&offset=0&telegram=true

```
{
  "nextOffset": -1,
  "portalData": [
    {
      "guid": "4c95b3ae447d4605a8421e21ace654c4.16",
      "lat": 59.47143,
      "lng": 24.887374,
      "name": "Tallinna Teletorn",
      "image": "http:\/\/lh3.ggpht.com\/GG_O7UHlFcqw6tlGvKPxU9jKZ9y-9oBiheIibRtQUP5Q-hZykSnDVrjzL5v_2SlgQmRxxirIAze79lDuDq1jbg",
      "address": "Kloostrimetsa tee 58a, 11913 Tallinn, Estonia"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

**Example 3:** https://lanched.ru/PortalGet/searchPortals.php?query=teletorn

```
[
  {
    "guid": "4c95b3ae447d4605a8421e21ace654c4.16",
    "lat": 59.47143,
    "lng": 24.887374,
    "image": "http:\/\/lh3.ggpht.com\/GG_O7UHlFcqw6tlGvKPxU9jKZ9y-9oBiheIibRtQUP5Q-hZykSnDVrjzL5v_2SlgQmRxxirIAze79lDuDq1jbg",
    "name": "Tallinna Teletorn",
    "address": "Kloostrimetsa tee 58a, 11913 Tallinn, Estonia"
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 4):

IITC is an open source browser plugin/mobile app that does it with a special plugin. http://iitc.jonatkins.com

Source code is available at github, so you might want to play with it. As it is noted by developer - "Using these scripts is likely to be considered against the Ingress Terms of Service. Any use is at your own risk."

Comment: I am looking for data, but if I understand correctly IITC is software, right? Can the portal **data** be downloaded somewhere on the IITC website? Or is IITC able to generate this database (in that case please detail the steps)? Thanks! :-)